# JavaFX Editable Cell value not update

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I created a TablView in javafx. The problem is that when I double click on a cell to update it, it converts it to textfield, after update record in cell when i click on another row having data, it doesn't not show updated record, but if i click on the same row or press tab, it updates the record.i am using textfield.focusProperty().

Actually it calls cancelEdit(), is there any way we can prevent it calling that function?

Comment: updated record and refresh the table data...

Comment: refreshing data is not updating record.

Comment: you have post that code.....

Comment: this is probably related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694616/how-to-enable-commit-on-focuslost-for-tableview-treetableview/25291137#25291137

Comment: @ymene you were quicker :-)