# Problems implementing an editable TableView<ObservableList<String>

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecelleditor

So I've been trying to implement a TableView where you can edit a column just by clicking on it, and then save the edit by pressing the enter key. I've taken at lot of the code from the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900344/how-to-make-a-table-column-with-integer-datatype-editable-without-changing-it-to) thread. This is the result:

```
import com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestEditableTable extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TableView<ObservableList<String>> tableView = new TableView<ObservableList<String>>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);

        // Some dummy data.
        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> dummyData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> firstRow = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Jack", "Smith");
        dummyData.add(firstRow);
        ObservableList<String> secondRow = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Peter", "Smith");
        dummyData.add(secondRow);

        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> firstCol = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>(
                "First name");
        firstCol.setCellValueFactory(
                (TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        param.getValue().get(0)));

        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> secondCol = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>(
                "Last name");
        secondCol.setCellValueFactory(
                (TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String> param) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        param.getValue().get(1)));

        secondCol.setCellFactory(cell -> new EditableCell());

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(firstCol, secondCol);

        tableView.getItems().addAll(dummyData);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    class EditableCell extends TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String> {

        private TextField textfield = new TextField();

        // When the user presses the enter button the edit is saved.
        public EditableCell() {
            setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                    commitEdit(textfield.getText());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (isEmpty()) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    textfield.setText(item);
                    setGraphic(textfield);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            textfield.setText(getItem());
            setGraphic(textfield);
            setText(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(getItem());
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(String value) {
            super.commitEdit(value);

            // This works. But gives me a "Discouraged access: The type 'ObservableListWrapper<String>' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')". 
            ObservableListWrapper<String> ob = ((ObservableListWrapper<String>) this.getTableRow().getItem());
            ob.set(1, value);

            // I had to put this in a Platform.runLater(), otherwise the textfield remained open.
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                setText(value);
                setGraphic(null);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And this program works OK. The cell is edited when you press the enter button. But there are two main issues with this:

1. Once I've pressed enter and a cell has been edited. I can't edit it again by clicking on it. I need to press another row to be able to edit it again. Setting to focus on the parent of the row didn't do the trick.
2. The code inside `commitEdit()` works. But it is ugly and using a `ObservableListWrapper` gives me the warning "Discouraged access: The type 'ObservableListWrapper' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')". Also the cell index is hard coded, which wont work if I use this in many different columns.

None of the issues mentioned above is acceptable.

The final implementation must support restriction of the input in the textfield. As far as I understand it this means that I need to have access to the `TextField` object displayed in the cell, as in my current implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the event handler as a key event handler on the **cell**. It makes more sense to register a handler on the text field, since that is the control on which the event of interest actually occurs. Note also that `TextField`s fire action events on pressing enter.

So replace

```
    public EditableCell() {
        setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                commitEdit(textfield.getText());
            }
        });
    }
```

with

```
    public EditableCell() {
        textfield.setOnAction(e -> commitEdit(textfield.getText()));
    }
```

This will make sure the editing state is properly maintained (which is not happening with your event handler, for reasons I can't quite figure out), so it fixes the issue of "re-editing". It also means you don't have to manually reset the text and graphic in `commitEdit`.

For the second issue, you can just downcast to `ObservableList<String>` instead of `ObservableListWrapper<String>`. But note you can also just do

```
    @Override
    public void commitEdit(String value) {
        super.commitEdit(value);
        ObservableList<String> row = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
        row.set(1, value);
    }
```

which not only avoids the private API, it avoids the downcast entirely.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks! I guess I could fix the hardcoded `row.set(1, value)` by just creating the columns in a for loop dynamically (save column names in a list and create a `TableColumn` for every element in the column name list) and passing the for loop integer to the constructor of the `EditableCell` if I have a lot of columns.

Answer (score 0):

An Other way is to replace JRE Library by JDK Library in your Buildpath 
Project->Build Path-> Configure build path
 -1 Remove JRE Library

-2 Add library
    -2.1 -> Select Java Library associated with your JDK environnement

All errors will disappear