# Making Table Column editable for float data types

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tableview, tablecolumn

I am sucessfull in making table column editable for those which refers to a `string` data type column of database table. But I am unsucessfull in doing the same with a `float` data type column of database table.

```
    tblColProductID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProductHeader, String>("Product_ID"));
    tblColProductName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    tblColProductName.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ProductHeader,String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<ProductHeader, String> t) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ((ProductHeader) t.getTableView().getItems()
                    .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setProduct_ID((String) t.getNewValue());
        }
```

The above `tblColProductID` refers to `ProductID` column which is has string datatype. But the code below gives me error in `setCellFactory`

```
tblColQuantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PurchaseDetail, Float>("Quantity"));
tblColQuantity.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
tblColQuantity.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<PurchaseDetail,Float>>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(CellEditEvent<PurchaseDetail, Float> t) {
    ((PurchaseDetail) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setQuantity((t.getNewValue()));
        }
    });
```

How do I make this second code work?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the error stack in your post?

Comment: It doesn't give any error message. When I hover to the error it says `The method setCellFactory(Callback<TableColumn<PurchaseDetail,Float>,TableCell<PurchaseDetail,Float>>) in the type 
 TableColumn<PurchaseDetail,Float> is not applicable for the arguments (Callback<TableColumn<Object,String>,TableCell<Object,String>>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have solved the problem and this is how I did it.

I refered to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27915420/5675550 which showed how to edit a table column with `int` datatype. I modified the code and made it work for `float` datatypes.

Here is the code :-

```
tblColQuantity.setCellFactory(col -> new IntegerEditingCell());

public class IntegerEditingCell extends TableCell<ProductHeader, Number> {
    private final TextField textField = new TextField();
    private final Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.\\d+");
    public IntegerEditingCell(){
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (! isNowFocused) {
                processEdit();
            }
        });
        textField.setOnAction(event -> processEdit());
    }

    private void processEdit() {
        String text = textField.getText();
        if (intPattern.matcher(text).matches()) {
            commitEdit(Float.parseFloat(text));
        } else {
            cancelEdit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Number value, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(value, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }else if (isEditing()) {
            setText(null);
            textField.setText(value.toString());
            setGraphic(textField);
        } else {
            setText(value.toString());
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        Number value = getItem();
        if (value != null) {
            textField.setText(value.toString());
            setGraphic(textField);
            setText(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(getItem().toString());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    // This seems necessary to persist the edit on loss of focus; not sure why:
    @Override
    public void commitEdit(Number value) {
        super.commitEdit(value);
        ((Item)this.getTableRow().getItem()).setValue(value.floatValue());
    }
}
```