# JavaFx: hide textfield in editable cell when focus leaves table

Tags: java, javafx

When user wants to edit a cell then a text field appears in this cell. How can I hide this textfield (close it) when user click something outside the table?

Comment: Do you have custom TableCell or used TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()?

Comment: @Uluk Biy I have used TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn().

Comment: possible duplicate of [TableView doesn't commit values on focus lost event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576577/tableview-doesnt-commit-values-on-focus-lost-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use custom `TableCell`, since the `TextFieldTableCell` does not support committing the edit on focus loosing.

See "*Example 12-11 Alternative Solution Of Cell Editing*" of this [Table View Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm).

Quoting from tutorial:

> Note that the default implementation of the TextField control requires
>   that users press the Enter key to commit the edit. You can redefine
>   the TextField behavior to commit the edit on the focus change, which
>   is an expected user experience. Try the modified code in to implement
>   such an alternative behavior.

Comment: "You can redefine the TextField behavior to commit the edit on the focus change, which is an expected user experience." This is what I am talking about. They understand what most of the users wait and do another way.